# UTF-8 is not working on the website it is shown this character f�r instead of für

Tags: html, symfony, twig

Hey i am using twig and symfony i am extending a base:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>{% block title %}test{% endblock %}</title>
  {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico}}"    

  />

 </head>
 <body>
 {% block body %}{% endblock %}
 {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
 </body>
 <footer>
 {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
 </footer>
 </html>
```

and extending it on twig

```
 {% extends 'testFEBundle:main:index.html.twig' %}
```

i used it before and i never had a problem. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening im using PhpStorm as an editor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows, by default, PhpStorm does't use UTF8. You must change settings and convert the file to UTF8.

Change settings: Go to File / Settings / Editor / File encoding menu and change options:  IDE encoding, project encoding and default encoding for properties files.

You can convert the PHP file to UF8 with NotePadd++ or other tool.